# python latex font xcode

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to use Matplotlib & Python in Xcode to generate scientific graphics. My boss would like them to be in LaTeX with matching fonts. I know you can modify the fonts in python with something like this:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Computer Modern Roman']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Unfortunately, opening or saving the figure with `plt.show()` or `plt.savefig()` gives a string of errors, eventually leading to `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

I know "Google is your friend", but I haven't managed to find anything on how to go about solving this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problems with usetex in OSX 10.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797480/problems-with-usetex-in-osx-10-8)

Comment: One of the answers in the linked question solved the problem, thanks! Adding the latex path in /usr/texbin into the xcode environment in the scheme allowed for latex fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually find it easiest to **directly specify the font file** I'm after.  Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager
from numpy import *

# cmunso.otf is a randomly selected font in my tex installation
path = '/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunso.otf'
f0 = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties()    
f0.set_file(path)

plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0,1.)
plt.ylim(0,1.)

d = arange(0, 1, .1)
plt.plot(d, d, "ob", label='example')

plt.text(.5, .1, 'text.. abcdef', fontproperties=f0, size=30)
plt.xlabel("x label", fontproperties=f0)
plt.legend(prop=f0, loc=2)
```

[image]

I'm not a font expert, but I think the reason this is easier is that font selection often has a cascading set of defaults for when the way you specify the font doesn't exactly match the way the system does.  The file, though, is easy to find and specify exactly (though it's obviously less portable).

Note that for `xlabel` and `text` the keyword is `fontproperties` and for `legend` it's `prop`.

Comment: One "drawback" with this solution is that math is being processed with mathtext (with specified font) rather than true LaTeX, giving slightly different end results.

Comment: While I ended up using a different way to solve this, the solution presented here works and is useful for other potential applications. If I understood it correctly, you could use this to get ANY font to be used in a figure, not just the ones python instinctively knows about.